# Buscar documentos insertando varios _id en mongoose

Tags: nodejs, mongoose

//mi intensión es buscar documentos en donde su `_id` coincidan con los id que tengo dentro de un array por el momento tengo esto

```
let publica = [ req.userId ]
  result.forEach((element: any) => {
         publica.push(element._id)
   });

productos.find({_id: {$in: publica}})
     .populate({path: 'usuarios'})
     .exec((err, result)=>{
         res.json(result)
     })
})
```

//tengo un array `result` que contiene objetos con un único campo te dipo `ObjetId` lo que hago es pasarlo por un `forEach` y rellenar el array `publica`, de esta forma tengo todos los `_id` en ese array, lo que quiero ahora es buscar en el modelo `productos`, todos los productos donde `_id` coincidan con los id del array `publica`

Si necesitan mas información con gusto los daré

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿Tu consulta no retorna los resultados? ¿No funciona la consulta? ¿Te da algún error? ¿Cuál?

Comment: lo que esto esta haciendo simplemente es devolverme un array vacio, pero es imposible por que tengo datos en el modelo productos

Comment: Entiendo, has probado individualmente? es decir, sin usar el operador `$in`, por ejemplo podrías hacer `productos.find({_id: results[0]._id}, ...);` para pasar sólo el primer elemento de tu lista y verificar si retorna al menos ese resultado. De lo contrario es difícil saber lo que pasa, ya que a simple vista todo el código se ve correcto.

Comment: probare trayendo de a un documento, te cuento en breve los resultados

Comment: pude solucionar el problema de la siguiente manera, al insertar cada id en el objeto no se guardo como un `ObjetId` sino como un simple string, agregue `publica.push(Mongoose.Types.ObjectId(`${element._id}`))`, de esta menera en pude lograr que mongoose busque esos ids